# In reduction from search LWE to decsion LWE why sampling needs to repeat a polynomial number of times?

Tags: provable-security, post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, lwe, reduction

I've been reading through MIT's lecture notes on learning with errors [here](https://people.csail.mit.edu/vinodv/6876-Fall2015/L13.pdf), and I'm trying to understand the reduction from Search LWE to Decision LWE, as described there in Section 2.7, "Algorithm 1".

I cannot seem to understand why we need to repeat the sampling part (for guessing the $i$th coordinate and feeding the sample to the discriminator) a polynomial number of times? ("$For\ l=1,\dots,L$"). Why can't we just choose the fist value for which the discriminator outputs $1$ (since it's more likely to output $1$ when the guess is correct)?

Answer (score 2):

The assumptions on the decider are weak - it has advantage at least $\epsilon$ (which you can imagine to be some small, but non-trivial quantity, say .01).

This is enough to break LWE. But the decider used in the reduction needs to have a *stronger* property. In particular, it needs to be *simultaneously correct* for all coordinates with good probability.

Concretely, you can think of the reduction flipping a coin with probability $(1/2)+\epsilon$ for each coordinate. The search reduction needs *all of these coins* to be heads with good probability. This will clearly not happen for $\epsilon$ small.

In light of this, the reduction first "boosts" the advantage of the decider, meaning turns a small $\epsilon$ decider into a decider with advantage close to 1. This is precisely the purpose of the loop you are talking about.